# Rational equivalence of cycles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to see why if $Y \subset \mathbb P^n$  is smooth, irreducible and closed, and $\pi : Y \to H$ a projection onto an hyperplane such that $\dim \pi (Y) = \dim Y$ then $\pi(Y) \sim Y$ where $\sim$ is the rational equivalence and $\pi(Y)$ is defined as a cycle by $\deg(\pi) \cdot \pi(Y)$.

My idea : for each $y \in Y$ consider the line between $y$ and $\pi(y)$. Put coordinate on this line such that $ 0 = y$ and $\infty = \pi(y)$. Then, take $W$ to be the union of such lines. Define $f : W \to k$as follows : any point $x \in W$ is on some line with given coordinate, and let $f(x)$ be this coordinate. Then we can see that $\text{div}(f) = Y - \deg(\pi)\pi(Y)$.

My problems are : $W$ is not really well defined since if $\pi(y) = y$ the line is not defined. Secondly I am not really convinced $f$ is a rational function, i.e how to see it is locally given by quotient of polynomial ? Its is locally given by a projection again if we restricts to every lines but I don't know how $f$ varies with the fibers.

If there is a simpler approach I would be happy to know it ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that $Y\sim e L$ where $L$ is a linear subspace of dimension $=\dim Y$ and $e=\deg Y$?

Comment: I know it only if $Y$ is an hypersurface, but if this is true I can look at the proof in an algebraic geometry book. So $Y \sim eL$ and $\pi(Y) \sim e' L$ so the only thing to check is $\deg(\pi(Y)) = \deg(\pi) \cdot \deg(Y)$ which seems ok (?)

Comment: @Mohan : Is this an easy result ? If no where can I find the proof ?

Comment: It is a standard result that the group of cycles of dimension $d$ in the projective space modulo rational equivalence is $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by the linear subspace of dimension $d$. Easiest proof is probably by localization and can be found almost everywhere (say Fulton, Intersection theory).

Comment: Ok, I am reading these notes : http://math.boisestate.edu/~zteitler/math/expository/chern.pdf and just learned about Chow groups today, so I was trying to prove this result by hand. Do you think my approach could work ? If no I would be happy with the proof in Fulton's book. Thanks again, everytime your comments are really helpful for me.

Comment: What is your approach?

Comment: @Mohan : I wanted to find $W$ with such that $W \cong \mathbb P^1 \times Y$ with $\{ \infty \} \times W = \pi(Y)$ (with appropriate multiplicity), and I took $W$ to be the union of line between $Y$ and $\pi(Y)$. My problem was if $\pi(y) = y$ such lines are not defined.

Comment: sorry I meant $W$ is the union of the lines between $y$ and $\pi(y)$ for $y \in Y$.

Comment: Explicit constructions like the ones you are trying will be usually difficult. That is why the abstract localization exact sequence is much easier, if less satisfactory. Please read a book.

Comment: I'll do it, thanks again.